# Spork auto-restart

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using `spork` as my DRB and `autotest` as my watcher to speed up testing in my Rails app. Currently, `autotest` restarts the testing when *a file in the directory structure* has changed.

Is there a way to restart `spork` after adding a new model? i.e. Restarting `spork` when **the directory structure** has changed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check Guard + guard-spork

https://github.com/guard/guard

https://github.com/guard/guard-spork

Guard is basically a listener with numerous extensions that let you watch various files for changes.
There's a recent Railscasts episode(264-guard) on the subject.

ADDITION per response:

Guard-spork sets the watch declarations as so:

```
guard 'spork' do
  watch('config/application.rb')
  watch('config/environment.rb')
  watch(%r{^config/environments/.*\.rb$})
  watch(%r{^config/initializers/.*\.rb$})
  watch('spec/spec_helper.rb')
end
```

To restart spork on a change to the directory structure, try fine-tuning the regex watch declarations.  In the case of restarting spork after adding a new model (why is that needed, if you don't mind my asking?) try the following which will catch any activity on .rb files,

```
watch(%r{^app/models/.*\.rb$})
```

otherwise, try the following to just catch wholesale changes to anything below the directory:

```
watch(%r{^config/initializers/.*})
```

Comment: guard watches files. do you now of any gem that watches directories?

Comment: I want to restart spork on adding new models because the `Spork.prefork` block that is executed before each run reads the file system. If a new resource is added - including spec tests for that resource, spork does not notice this change.